# How to show the determinant of a matrix is zero for which the column elements sum to zero

Tags: matrices, determinant

It is given that the sum of the elements of each column of a $N\times N$ square matrix ${\rm A}$ is zero. How can I show that the determinant is zero without specializing to $N=2$ or $N=3$?

Comment: You can observe that last row would be linear combination of other rows, and hence det must be zero.

Comment: A similar question had been asked sometime back where the sum of elements of each row was a constant. Then thanks to a well known theorem, that constant must be an eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector of all ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$det(A) = = det \left( \begin{matrix}a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_{n-1}\\a_n \end{matrix} \right) = det \left( \begin{matrix}a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_{n-1} \\a_1 + \cdots +a_n \end{matrix} \right) = det \left( \begin{matrix}a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_{n-1}\\0 \end{matrix} \right) = 0$

Where $a_i$ are the row vectors of $A$.

Of course, within the matrix $0$ stands for the row vector $0 = (0 \ldots 0)$.

Comment: How can you take the determinant of column vectors? Probably you're using some abbreviation and you're trying to point out that all elements of one row can be made equal to zero. Is that right?

Comment: $a_i = (a_{i1} \ldots a_{in})$. I just chose an often used abbreviation of writing a matrix, if it is only necessary to consider the matrix as a column of row vectors or a row of column vectors.

Comment: Fact is, when you sum to the last row all other rows (which does not change the determinant), you get the zero-vector in the last row because of the condition that the sum of the elements in each column is equal zero.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the matrix is $(a_{ij}$, you have $a_{ni}=\sum_{j=1}^{j=n-1}-a_{ji}$, if you sum the first $n-1$ line you have the last line with the opposite sign.